# How can old, low-quality answers be dealt with?

Tags: discussion

Let me start off with a collection of old, low-quality answers. These answers *sometimes* attempt to answer the question, but not well.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3433914/2446155:

> E.g. via en event.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1839986/2446155:

> This is not a bug.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1502480/2446155:

> use Convert class

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2452033/2446155- Now deleted (not as a result of my flag):

> You can use Ajax.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52463/2446155:

> Try SVN or TFS.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/812221/2446155:

> No
> .

*In my haste and ignorance*, I flagged all of the above as `it is not an answer`. The flag description:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the
> question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question,
> or deleted altogether.

Okay, so maybe they *barely* tried to answer the question, but they certainly weren't quality answers. As one moderator [in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2290401#2290401) said regarding [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1502480/2446155):

> Well it does answer the question, however poorly.

All of my flags for the above answers were denied, understandably.

At the time, I considered flagging them VLQ, however I instead figured that these old, rarely seen answers didn't need to be deleted *immediately*. [To quote a moderator](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2285451#2285451):

> ...VLQ is supposed to be for stuff that is utter crap that should be gone immediately.

So what am I supposed to do with *utter crap* that *doesn't* necessarily need to be deleted *immediately*?

Comment: Do exactly what you should have done in the first place. Downvote them (and if you want flag as VLQ). Sufficient downvotes will enable the delete option, and the answer can then be deleted; once that happens (or the poster deletes it because of the high number of negative votes), you'll regain the reputation you lost for downvoting.

Comment: @KenWhite Would VLQ have been appropriate given that they were old, and didn't need to be gone _immediately_

Comment: VLQ applies any time they're very low quality, and puts the flag in the VLQ review queue for 10K+ readers to review. Sufficient agreements with the flag will cause it to be deleted without a moderator's involvement. I've just flagged four of the posts you linked as VLQ, as well as downvoting them (and in one case casting a delete vote as it has a score of -4 at this point).

Comment: @KenWhite How're those VLQ flags working out?

Comment: @KenWhite the 10k+ flag queue is kaput

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So what am I supposed to do with utter crap that doesn't necessarily need to be deleted immediately?

You down vote it.

When it achieves sufficient negative score trusted users (>20K rep) can vote to delete the answer - unless it is the marked answer. In these cases the only real action that can be taken is to flag it as *Not an answer*, these particular ones go straight to the ♦ moderators queue, and you take your chance about whether a mod will accept the flag and delete the answer.

For some real low quality ones that are the marked answer (like this [super example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1839986/109702) you linked) there is another possibility: if the question is crap then you can vote down or vote to close/delete the question. This specific example is a moderately up-voted question, but it's been closed for a couple of years and the crap answer was it's only answer, so it can go.

For other non-marked gems [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/812221/109702) use the VLQ flag which will get the answer placed into a review queue. I think you are too focused on the word *immediately* - forget about that and consider *does the answer serve any purpose whatsoever?* If it doesn't then it is just adding noise and detracting from quality, so the sooner it is gone the better.

Comment: These posts don't typically get much traffic. They are unlikely to receive enough downvotes. How are trusted users (>20k) supposed to know to vote to delete the question if it is not flagged?

Comment: @SantaClaus I was writing a comment to answer your comment, but I decided to add it into the answer instead. Getting these items into a queue via flagging is fine, you just need to be careful for the specific flags or combinations of conditions that will see it end up in the mod queue - mods are for doing important stuff, not for general janitorial work.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using VLQ for really old questions and answers because of [this](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2285451#2285451)

Comment: @SantaClaus All due (and huge amount of) respect to bluefeet - I would suggest she was possibly commenting on the flag being used excessively when an answer should simply have been down voted. Many of your examples should be gone as soon as possible because they are crap, pure and simple. This flag simply gets an item placed into a queue for further review, try to avoid the circumstances where it will go to a mod queue because the mods don't need to be involved in this sort of mundane thing. I'll ping her and see if I can get her to leave a comment/answer here too to help clarify things.

Comment: @SantaClaus Just to elaborate, there is [this comment from bluefeet](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2285468#2285468) a couple of minutes later - people would be using the VLQ flag for stuff that they don't necessarily like or agree with - they should be voting instead of flagging.

Comment: I'll back up slugster here - VLQ should be used for unmitigated crap *regardless* of age. This does not extend to answers which you merely feel are wrong or less helpful than they should be though; VLQ is not a substitute for downvoting, even though they should often be used together.

Comment: The problem that I'm seeing as a mod is people are using the VLQ wrong and are going on mass flag sprees based on a query. Many of these flags we are getting are not correct and people are flagging without looking at the question, other answers on the post, etc. Not every short answer needs to be flagged LQ (which seems to be the trend). Read the post, does it answer the question? If so, great. Does it deserve a downvote? If so, then vote. If not, then move along. **Please don't blindly flag stuff based off a query.**

Comment: @Shog9 But a NAA flag wasn't appropriate?

Comment: NAA is for things that are quite literally *not intended as answers*, @SantaClaus. VLQ covers "too bad to really tell". Downvotes are for answers that are merely wrong.

Comment: @Shog9 So VLQ might apply to many of the "yes" or "no" answers [in this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/216999/283507/short-answers), except that you don't want people to go flagging a bunch from a query? Or is it okay as long as I look at each answer and make sure it really is low quality?

Comment: It might. Just make damn sure that you understand the question, and understand that a terse answer isn't actually a perfectly appropriate/correct answer to the question before you do anything else. They're rare, but... I've seen folks flag accepted answers to actual "yes/no" questions when that was quite literally the only correct answer *and* it even included links to relevant documentation. If the mods get the idea that you're just blindly scripting away your flags, they're probably gonna just script away the declines...

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks. That makes sense. Is there some mod siren that sounds if I flag a bunch of things at once? Should I try to flag things in smaller batches?

Comment: The more you're flagging at once, the better your accuracy rate should be. If you're not 100% certain, slow down until you are. @Santa.

Comment: @Shog9 Ok. Just by going through the first few  of those that happened to be in that query, the question is frequently just a yes/no question, so the answers were likely acceptable and wouldn't need flagging.